# Elasticsearch terms query only working on _id field

Tags: elasticsearch

I've been trying to do the equivalent of an IN query. The simplest method i've found for the purposes of illustrating the problem is this:

GET {URL}/index/_search

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "id": [ "0b54ffc1-cea9-4e5d-9766-559720621922", "0658115e-60b3-439d-9f1a-343ab914806b"],
      "boost": 1.0
    }
  }
}
```

This returns me no hits, even though i have documents with those ID fields.
If however i use the _id which for this index is the same i get results, ie.

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "_id": [ "0b54ffc1-cea9-4e5d-9766-559720621922", "0658115e-60b3-439d-9f1a-343ab914806b"],
      "boost": 1.0
    }
  }
}
```

I actually want to use a completely different field which is 'user.id' (im indexing a nested firebase field), this doesnt work either but the example above is particularly confusing.

Just to validate this i've attached a screenshot showing kibana results for rows where you have the same value in two fields and the field im interested in.

Thanks for anyones help!

Dan

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you check your mapping, your `id` field might be of type `text`. You might have a sub-field called `id.keyword` which is of type `keyword` and if that's the case you can achieve what you need by using that sub-field instead:

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "id.keyword": [ "0b54ffc1-cea9-4e5d-9766-559720621922", "0658115e-60b3-439d-9f1a-343ab914806b"],
      "boost": 1.0
    }
  }
}
```